# Who Calls the First OnLoad Call in Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

asp.net 3.5
Ive been sitting with the Reflector to find out - who is First(!) calling the OnLoad Method which activates the event for all subscribers
i didnt find it.

im not talking about the AutoEvenntWireup situation ( which is not relevant here) because this stage happens later...

im talking about  : who first Activates the Control.OnLoad Method ??
i want to see it in the reflector and could find the activation ! i can find only the Method signature

Comment: Try to break in debugger and see call stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page.ProcessRequestMain()` calls `Page.LoadRecursive()`, which in turn calls `Page.OnLoad()`.

The relevant code (disassembled with ILSpy) is:

```
internal virtual void LoadRecursive()
{
    if (this._controlState < ControlState.Loaded) {
        if (this._adapter != null) {
            this._adapter.OnLoad(EventArgs.Empty);
        } else {
            this.OnLoad(EventArgs.Empty);  // ** Here. **
        }
    }
    if (this._occasionalFields != null
        && this._occasionalFields.Controls != null) {
        string collectionReadOnly
            = this._occasionalFields.Controls.SetCollectionReadOnly(
                "Parent_collections_readonly");
        int count = this._occasionalFields.Controls.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this._occasionalFields.Controls[i].LoadRecursive();
        }
        this._occasionalFields.Controls.SetCollectionReadOnly(
            collectionReadOnly);
    }
    if (this._controlState < ControlState.Loaded) {
        this._controlState = ControlState.Loaded;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot... how did you find it ? by navigating from one to each other without knowing or there was a specific search path which led you to this ? cause i tried to search it by logic and could find it..

Comment: I've seen quite a few ASP.NET stack traces now, so I knew `ProcessRequestMain()` was involved. I looked for the `Load` phase there and followed down `LoadRecursive()`.

Comment: Thanks! youve just answered my first quesion on StackOverFlow.